# Cauchy Problem and Region of Validity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have the Cauchy Problem

$$ 2xu_x+(x+y)u_y=2u $$
with data

$$ u(x,-x)=\sqrt{x},x>0$$

Omitting details, my answer is

$$u(x,y) =\sqrt{x}\left ( \frac{y}{2x}-\frac{1}{2} \right)^{-\frac{1}{3}} $$

or

$$u(x,y) =\frac{2^{\frac{1}{3}}x^{\frac{5}{6}}}{\left ( y-x \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} } $$

If you solve the Cauchy problem, do you arrive at the same $u(x,y)$?  What about the region of validity?

It seems this becomes invalid when $y=x$ and when $x<0$, so I propose that my region of validity is $x>0$, $y<x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution **of the PDE** is given by:

> $$\color{blue}{u(x,y) = f\left(\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{x}} \right) \, x, \quad x > 0} \tag{1}$$

for some arbitrary function $f$.

In the other hand, the solution **of the Cauchy problem** is:

> $$\color{blue}{ u(x,y) = 2x \, \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-y}, \quad y \neq x, \ \ x>0}  \tag{2} $$

What happens when $x=0$ is left to the reader.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

---

***Edit***:

Here's a contour plot of the solution where the region $x=y$ is highlighted:

[image]

Comment: Reworking the problem got me this solution.  I also got that the characteristics were

$$y=x+\frac{2Bx}{x-y}$$ 

These are valid for $y\neq x$, so it seems that since the data is in the fourth quadrant, the region in which our solution is valid is $y<x$ and $x>0$.  Do you agree?

Comment: Hello @InfiniteDifferenceMethod. Why shouldn't be the solution valid for, say $(x,y) = (1,2)$, i.e., for $y>x$?

Comment: You cannot connect this point to the data through characteristic s.  I think.

Comment: The characteristic curves tells you where the solution is constant through, not where the solution is valid; generally speaking.

Comment: Well how does one determine where the solution is valid?

Comment: Just looking to eq. (1), where you can see that $x>0$ is the domain where $u$ is defined. Note that, when BCs are applied, a restriction on the domain comes up, i.e., $x \neq y$. Thus, the domain of the solution of the Cauchy problem is $x > 0$ and $x \neq y$. You can work out what happens in the cases $x =0$ and/or $x = y$.

Comment: So what characteristic curve links $(1,2)$ to the data?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you mean by *linking a point to the data*.

Comment: Every point in the valid region has a characteristic curve linking that point to the cauchy data.

Comment: Sorry again, but I fail to see why hte domain of definition of the solution should not been the one I have posted in my answer. Let somebody shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=2x$ , letting $x(0)=1$ , we have $x=e^{2t}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=x+y=e^{2t}+y$ , letting $y(0)=y_0+1$ , we have $y=e^{2t}+y_0e^t=x+y_0\sqrt x$

$\dfrac{du}{ds}=2u$ , letting $u(0)=f(y_0)$ , we have $u(x,y)=f(y_0)e^{2t}=f\left(\dfrac{y-x}{\sqrt x}\right)x$

$u(x,-x)=\sqrt x$ :

$f(-2\sqrt x)x=\sqrt x$

$f(-2\sqrt x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x}$

$f(-2x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$

$f(x)=-\dfrac{2}{x}$

$\therefore u(x,y)=-\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{y-x}{\sqrt x}}\times x=\dfrac{2x^\frac{3}{2}}{x-y}$